# Dispose unused resources in c# winform application GLOBALLY

Tags: c#

How to Dispose unused resources in c# winform application GLOBALLY ??

Comment: Could you give us some more details of exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am creating a custom taskbar like windows which works fine. But when i close the application, the space occupied by taskbar is blocked. So i want to force the GC.  From the below explanation i understood some stuffs. But where to call it Globally ??

Comment: It might help if you share with us the method for creating the toolbar -- I'm presuming it's not just an "always on top" window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force garbage collection by doing:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

This is assuming you follow the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) pattern. Codeproject has quite a [detailed article on the `IDisposable` pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx)

Comment: forcing a garbage collection is rarely the right thing to do; it can actually promote the lifetime of objects in some circumstances...

Comment: "This is assuming you follow the `IDisposable` pattern" - the two have very little connection...

Comment: This approach does not require IDisposable, just Finalizers. Proper implementation and use of IDisposable would solve the problem underlying this question.

Comment: The question was to call Dispose on unused objects - If it's unused, it is able to be garbage collected - to force Dispose to be called, you need to call it in the Finalize - i.e. implement IDisposable

Comment: @Rowland: The `IDisposable` contract doesn't require a finalizer.

Comment: I was talking about the recommended *pattern* for implementing the interface, rather than the interface itself.

Comment: Rowland, I'm quite sure the OP used the word 'Dispose' to mean just "clean up", not necessarily through Dispose(). As such only a Finalizer is required, that may or may not be part of IDisposable.

Answer (score 5):

Terminate the process

Comment: It was a stupid answer to the question, I know, but I get the feeling that this question is masking a larger level of rot.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can force a garbage collection (`GC.Collect`)*, but that isn't the same as `Dispose()` - and of course, if your code can see it (to dispose it), it can't be collected. So introducing extra models to track them yourself could be counter-productive.

I suggest simply making sure you make appropriate use of `using` blocks, and make sure your code knows what "owns" an `IDisposable` resource. This gets a bit tricky with pens / brushes / etc, as the *system* brushes (etc) need to be treated differently to your own custom brushes.

*=and as Mitch notes, this is rarely the right thing to do; I typically only use `GC.Collect` from test rigs to flatten things between test cycles... not in production code.

Comment: @Marc: might be worth mentioning that forcing a garbage collection is rarely the right thing to do; it can actually promote the lifetime of objects in some circumstances...